# Wget batch script for call repeatedly url

Tags: windows, batch-file, wget

I need a wget batch script for call repeatedly a localhost url if status code is 200

is possibile something like it?

```
if(wget_status == 200) {
     wget -q "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
}
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by recursive here?

Comment: @FZs I need to reload this script > wget -q "127.0.0.1:5000" until status return '200' and abort if status return '404'

Comment: I solved with wget --read-timeout=5 "http://127.0.0.1:5000"